# Not able to detect branch from Git post-receive hook

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

I've got a post receive hook setup on the remote repo that tries to determine the branch name of the incoming push as follows:

```
$branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

What i'm finding, though, is that no matter what branch I push from my $branch variable gets set with 'master'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The post-receive hook gets the same data as the pre-receive and not as arguments, but from stdin. The following is sent for all refs:

oldRev (space) newRev (space) refName (Line feed)

You could parse out the ref name with this bash script:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    echo "$ref"
done
```

Comment: except beware if `post-receive` is receiving a `git push --tags` for example (and probably `git push origin my_tagname`) then the `ref` you'll be getting is `refs/tags/my_tagname` and *not*  `refs/branch/my_branchname`

Comment: How can I switch to the previous commit, in **post-receive** hook?

Answer (score 10):

You could also do something like this using bash variable substitution:

```
read oldrev newrev ref

branchname=${ref#refs/heads/}

git checkout ${branchname}
```

Comment: Perfect, and then combine with @ralphtheninja's loop to read all when multiple branches are pushed

Answer (score 2):

Magnus' solution didnt work for me, but [this](https://gist.github.com/3697539) did:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "determining branch"

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
  read -a ref
fi

IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
branch="${REF[2]}"

if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
  echo 'master was pushed'
fi

if [ "staging" == "$branch" ]; then
  echo 'staging was pushed'
fi

echo "done"
```

Comment: That's because you are looking for the word master, but what you received was refs/head/master. Using read you turned the string into an array delimited by '/'. Then you plucked out the value.

Comment: Hi Can you help on how to add `and` condition in `if` like `if ["master" == "$branch" && "development"=="$branch"]`. How to use and condition in this if in hook. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both these answers are correct, but I was having trouble getting stdin to the next common function post-receive-email. Here is what I ended up with:

```
read oldrev newrev ref
echo "$oldrev" "$newrev" "$ref" | . /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email


if [ "refs/heads/qa" == "$ref" ]; then
  # Big Tuna YO!
  wget -q -O - --connect-timeout=2 http://127.0.0.1:3000/hooks/build/qa_now
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the arguments that are being passed to the script. That should have the branch name and new and old revisions and run for each branch pushed