# how to process files on a branch in post-receive hook in git

Tags: git, githooks

I have a remote server on which I have created a bare git repository.

I would like to create a hook so that a given script is run on the latest code received on any given branch.

I know the `post-receive` hook can be used for it. However I want to do the following:

1. Get hold of the branch on which code was received.
2. Checkout the code in a temp location and run an operation on it.

How do I do the above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- For 1), you have an example of reading the branch name (through stdin):
  "[Not able to detect branch from Git post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973795/not-able-to-detect-branch-from-git-post-receive-hook)"
- For 2), you need to set GIT_WORK_TREE appropriately:
  "[Managing website using git + post-receive hook: error pushing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902551/managing-website-using-git-post-receive-hook-error-pushing-changes/10903184#10903184)"

See both techniques combined in "[Git post-receive for multiple remote branches and work-trees](http://blog.ekynoxe.com/2011/10/22/git-post-receive-for-multiple-remote-branches-and-work-trees/)":

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/path/under/root/dir/live-site/ checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed live.'
  fi

  if [ "dev" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/path/under/root/dir/dev-site/ checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to dev.'
  fi
done
```