# Automate cp head of git repository to webserver directory

Tags: git, repository, cp

I created a git repository on my webserver to manage my website sources and I want to automatically copy all updated files into my /srv/http directory so after every push to the master branch my website updates.

How can I do this?

Comment: I write my code on my Desktop PC or Laptop and need the webserver to test changes to my php code - as such it is a great hassle to always access my webserver's /srv/http via ftp and copy the files over - I would much rather automate this by simply pushing the files via git and then automate the process of updating the files on the actual server directory

Comment: There are plenty of different [auto-deploy examples Out There](https://www.google.com/#q=git+deploy+hook).  The main issues are deciding what gets deployed where, and how to handle permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many example, as noted by torek, note that:

- most involves a post-receive hook
- you can filter on the branch being pushed in such an hook.

See for instance "[how to process files on a branch in post-receive hook in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309)".

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    ...
```