# Gitolite update copy at server when push

Tags: gitolite

In gitolite I've set up a new repository on the server and able to clone it from my machine.
As it's a web project I need the latest working copy at /var/www/my-project, so every push made by a developer will update the files there. How can I achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repos managed by gitolite are managed in ~/repositories

You can add your own hook in `~/repositories/yourrepo.git/hooks` called [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) in order to checkout, on each push, the index to a working tree of your choice (like 
`/var/www/my-project`)

See for instance "[how to process files on a branch in post-receive hook in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309)" (which can even check for which branch is pushed).

The checkout uses:

```
git checkout --work-tree=/var/www/my-project
```